# Collatz Conjecture Numbers up to n

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I was playing around with the Collatz sequences of numbers up to a number. My question was, for which numbers $n$ does no integer below $n$ reach $n$ in its iteration? 
So I wrote a program to find all the ones that have that property and I quickly realized all multiples of 3 do. Obviously, because $3n + 1$ can never be a multiple of 3 and if it's not already a multiple of 3, dividing by 2 obviously won't make it one.

However, what I noticed after that is that the rest of the numbers are almost all primes. Only some primes, however, and I'm not sure what the criteria for it is. A small percent of them are also numbers that have some number of prime factors, and as you go up into the higher numbers of course the number of prime factors on average increases. None of these numbers are even for unknown reasons to me that I'm sure I could figure out if I looked hard enough.

Consequently, the percent of these numbers that are prime decreases as you go for higher values of $n$, but remains higher than you'd expect. Of course, there are lots of primes because any number in the list has to be odd, and can't be divisible by 3 because I excluded those because they're trivial.

However, my question is, what, if any, are the criteria for any number that satisfies this property (no integer below $n$ reaches $n$ in its iteration)? Besides not being a multiple of 3 I couldn't come up with any solid reasoning.

As a bonus, is it really true that all numbers even and not divisible by 3 have some number below it whose sequence includes it? And if so, why?

Comment: For numbers up to 100000:
43266 have this property, 
29763 of those are multiples of 3, 
7964 are two primes multiplied, 
2851 are primes, 
2687 are three primes multiplied or higher

Comment: I would type the numbers into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences to see what turns up.

Comment: $2x+1$ goes through $6x+4$ and $3x+2$ thus elimination all primes that have remainder 5 on division by 6.

Comment: where does $2x+1$ come into it

Comment: So have you consulted the OEIS yet?

Comment: yep I did and I understand they're pure numbers now

Comment: I don't know what "pure numbers" are. But maybe you could summarize what you found at OEIS, and post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today, Tiger.

Comment: @TigerGold This tree that I made may be of interest to you.
Look at the values (mod 6) and it will tell you what the colours mean
https://coggle.it/diagram/V4JAwIs_e54GqINA/t/collatz-3s-drop-tree

Comment: It's clear that no even number will appear in this list, because each even is either a multiple of $3$ (which you already know about), or it is of the form $3k+1$, putting it in the trajectory of $k$, or it is of the form $3k+2$, putting it in the trajectory of $2k+1$.